# Selecting only a portion of a long text/varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a `notes` field, datatype `text`, that in our application is a general purpose notepad specific to that order. The problem is that on older orders, this field is large and unwieldy, as some departments entered data that should have been in their own fields. We are now trying to separate this data into actual fields after the fact as much as possible.

An example portion of the `notes` field:

```
...
05/12 Serve all $w/check. Ins here. Per recording-RSM  (A-F)-1395   (G-O)-104786        (P-Z)-177015  *Unable to verify Billing/PT recs(07/12 LO)(08/12MH)    

***EXPEDITORS : info I want here

(More junk data here)
...
```

Is there a way for selecting only the remainder of the string after the word `EXPEDITORS`, to aid in data entry? There is no consistent 'end' character or string, but it would be sufficient to have the data at the beginning of the field.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT id, notes 
FROM table 
WHERE notes LIKE '%EXPEDITOR%'
```

Note: I know `text` datatype is old; converting to `VARCHAR(MAX)` is acceptable for the purposes of this query if necessary.

edit: To clarify, my ideal output would be the following:

```
***EXPEDITORS : info I want here
```

but it can include everything that follows as well. I am mostly looking to remove the junk in front of the keyword `EXPEDITOR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(notes,
                 PATINDEX('%EXPEDITOR%', notes), 
                (DATALENGTH(notes) - PATINDEX('%EXPEDITOR%', notes))) 
FROM table
```

This returns the text starting with the `EXPEDITORS` keyword. It still contains the rest of the junk after the info, but this will work fine anyway since it will be read by humans and entered.

The keys were the `SUBSTRING` function and the `DATALENGTH` function (the latter being required for the `text` datatype).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use substr/instr. These are Oracle queries but they will work in any SQL:

```
SELECT Substr(str, Instr(str, 'EXPEDITORS :')+Length('EXPEDITORS :')+1 ) str FROM
 (
  SELECT '05/12 Serve all $w/check. Ins here. Per recording-RSM....***EXPEDITORS : More Junk Data is what we want' AS str
    FROM dual
 )
 /
```

OR if you have always have ':' after word EXPEDITORS then:

```
SELECT Trim(Substr(str, Instr(str, ':')+1 )) str FROM
(
 SELECT '05/12 Serve all $w/check. Ins here. Per recording-RSM....***EXPEDITORS : More Junk Data is what we want' AS str
 FROM dual
)
/
```

In both cases the output is this:

```
str
--------------------------------
More Junk Data is what we want
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid TSQL. The OP is on SQL Server.

Comment: @Martin, the INSTR/SUBSTR functions are part of ANSI SQL as far as I know. The dual table is Oracle specific. Replace it with your table and it should work. I always run/test my queries before posting them. I'm not smart enough to crunch such things in my mind.

Comment: I'm not the OP. But I can clarify for you that none of `Trim`,`Substr`,`Instr` are functions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with substring_index (or substr + instr) + reverse

In fact, here is the evolution of the query :

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(data), REVERSE('EXPEDITORS'), 1)) 
FROM yourtable
```

This query return :

```
: info I want here
(More junk data here)
...
```

Then :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(data), REVERSE('EXPEDITORS'), 1)), '\n', 1)
FROM yourtable
```

This query return :

```
: info I want here
```

And to finish :

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(data), REVERSE('EXPEDITORS'), 1)), '\n', 1), ': ', '')
FROM yourtable
```

Wich returns :

```
info I want here
```

EDIT : In MySQL / Oracle
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(
REVERSE(SUBSTR(data, INSTR(data, 'EXPEDITORS : ')+LENGTH('EXPEDITORS : '))),
LENGTH(SUBSTR(data, INSTR(data, 'EXPEDITORS : ')+LENGTH('EXPEDITORS : '))) - INSTR(SUBSTR(data, INSTR(data, 'EXPEDITORS : ')+LENGTH('EXPEDITORS : ')), '\n')))
FROM mytable

Comment: Is your method valid in SQL Server 2005? I'm getting the error: `'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: Oh it was an example in MySQL.
And here maybe in T-SQL (i can't try it) :
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(
REVERSE(SUBSTR(txt, PATINDEX ('%EXPEDITORS : %', txt)+LENGTH('EXPEDITORS : '))),
LENGTH(SUBSTR(txt, PATINDEX ('%EXPEDITORS : %', txt)+LENGTH('EXPEDITORS : '))) - PATINDEX('%\n%', SUBSTR(txt, PATINDEX('%EXPEDITORS : %', txt)+LENGTH('EXPEDITORS : ')))))
FROM testtext